# How do I access a custom property from another component in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

How do I access a custom property from another Unity component?

In my Avatar component I have declared the variable like this:

```
public var isInEndzone : boolean;
```

Calling the property from another component:

```
//actor variable is the GameObject that has the Avatar component.
public var avatar : GameObject;

....

var avatarComponent : Avatar = avatar.GetComponent(Avatar);
if (avatarComponent.IsInEndzone){
//do something...
}
```

Error:

```
GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Avatar' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
UnityEngine.GameObject:GetComponent(Type)

BCE0019: 'IsInEndzone' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Avatar'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I GOT IT! You cannot use the reserved name Avatar, apparently that is already a class, change the name to something else and it will work.

Comment: OR add this to your statement: var avatarComponent : Avatar = avatar.gameObject.GetComponent(Avatar);

Comment: I changed it to var avatarComponent : Avatar = avatar.gameObject.GetComponent("Avatar"); but now get: BCE0022: Cannot convert 'UnityEngine.Component' to 'UnityEngine.Avatar'.

Comment: Can you post your Avatar class, and what is the avatar variable?

Comment: Avatar class is to big to post, but the avatar variable is set from the Unity IDE

Comment: Is avatar attached directly to the avatar GameObject? You may want to try avatar.GetComponentInChildren() Referenced here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html

Comment: Yes the GameObject is directly attached to the avtar

Comment: On a second glance, change your variable name to have a lowercase i

IsInEndzone to isInEndzone

Comment: Already tried changing the case of i, I am starting to think this is not possible in Unity. Perhaps you have to use SendMessage to communicate between components.

Comment: Its hard to see without all the code, its possible. Try the unity forums. That usually helps me.

Comment: Thanks, I have yet to get a response from any post on those forums. I will have to just work around this issue. I am surprised no one has tried to get a property from a custom component before.

Comment: How do I inherit from MonoBehaviour in JavaScript?

Comment: It is done automatically "Using Javascript every script automatically derives from MonoBehaviour. When using C# or Boo you have to explicitly derive from MonoBehaviour."  http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html